# how to fix java Spring bean Autowire Cannot handle (123) '{'

Tags: spring, autowired, spring-framework-beans

I want to insert Spring Basics: Dynamically Inject Values With Spring’s @Value. How can I do it?

I tried with the code

```
@Value("#{{2: 'Catch22', 22: '1984', 32: 'Pride and Prejudice'}}")
```

but I got exception

```
private Map <Integer,String>studentTeacherMap;
@Value("#{{2: 'Catch22', 22: '1984', 32: 'Pride and Prejudice'}}")
public Map<Integer, String> loki()
return studentTeacherMap;
```

I expect the output to be

```
2= Catch22, 22= 1984, 32= Pride and Prejudice
```

but ended up with the exception:

`Cannot handle (123) '{'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register this map as a Bean, consider put it into `@Configuration` annotated class:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {
    @Value("#{{2: 'Catch22', 22: '1984', 32: 'Pride and Prejudice'}}")
    private Map<Integer, String> lokiMap;

    @Bean
    public Map<Integer, String> lokiMap() {
        return lokiMap;
    }
}
```

And inject this bean in class where you want to use it:

```java
@Autowired
private Map<Integer, String> lokiMap;
```

Or you can use the map directly without declaring it as a bean, but in such case you don't need `@Autowired` annotation, just put `@Value` under map:

```java
@Value("#{{2: 'Catch22', 22: '1984', 32: 'Pride and Prejudice'}}")
private Map<Integer, String> lokiMap;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, as you mentioned I used Autowire bean configuration, now i got a new Exception which is

Comment: Key type [class java.lang.Integer] of map [java.util.Map] must be assignable to [java.lang.String]

Comment: @Bean
 public Map<Integer, String> getStudentTeacherMap() 
 {
  return studentTeacherMap;
 }

 @Value("#{{1: 'Catch-22', 2: '1984', 3: 'Pride and Prejudice'}}")
 public void setStudentTeacherMap(Map<Integer, String> studentTeacherMap) {
  this.studentTeacherMap = studentTeacherMap;
 }

Comment: @Loki first, your ```@Bean``` method name should be named "studentTeacherMap". If you set method's name to "getStudentTeacherMap", the resulting bean's name will be: "getStudentTeacherMap", but not "studentTeacherMap". In your case it worked, because autowiring is performing firstly by type of a bean.

Second, I can't reproduce the error you mentioned. Can you provide full code?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured the error code, in the beginning, I mentioned "Cannot handle (123) '{' ", this is because, before I used Spring version 2.5.6, now I changed it to 5.1.3.RELEASE now it can handle the error code and got the output.  Thank you for your help.